# Type 'Provider<T>' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am creating a component that used to compose all providers into an array to avoid nested providers but I getting an TypeScript error:

> Type 'Provider' must have a 'Symbol.iterator' method that
> returns an iterator.ts(2488)

The error above appears at line `const [ProviderComponent, props] = curr;`. How do i fix this error?

Here is my code:

```
import type { Provider, ReactNode } from 'react';

interface ComposeProviderProps<TValue> {
   providers: Provider<TValue>[];
   children: ReactNode;
}
export default function ComposeProvider<T>({ providers, children }: ComposeProviderProps<T>) {
   return (
      <>
         {providers.reduceRight((acc, curr) => {
            const [ProviderComponent, props] = curr; // <=== TS Error here

            return <ProviderComponent {...props}>{acc}</ProviderComponent>;
         }, children)}
      </>
   );
}
```

An example for the use case of the above code:

```
<ComposeProvider providers={[<Provider1 />, <Provider2 />, <Provider3 />]}>
 ...children
</ComposeProvider>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define an array of providers, but the providers themselves are not Arrays. You cannot destructure them like Arrays (or something iterable).
That's what the error message tells you, they're not iterable.

They are of type `ReactElement`. So it would be: `const {type: ProviderComponent, props } = curr;`

but take a look at [cloneElement](https://react.dev/reference/react/cloneElement)

```
import type { Provider, ReactNode, cloneElement } from 'react';

interface ComposeProviderProps<TValue> {
   providers: Provider<TValue>[];
   children: ReactNode;
}
export default function ComposeProvider<T>({ providers, children }: ComposeProviderProps<T>) {
   return (
      <>
         {providers.reduceRight((acc, curr) => cloneElement(curr, null, acc), children)}
      </>
   );
}
```

Comment: It works like a charm! Huge thanks.